# trouble in GetEnumerator in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, viewport3d

i want to  change all material color in the view port 3d using this code :

```
    DiffuseMaterial mat = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));

        foreach (ModelVisual3D model3d in previewport.Children)
        {

            foreach (GeometryModel3D item in model3d.Content)
            {
                item.Material = mat;
            }
        }
```

but it get errors :

```
      Error  
     foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Model3D' because 'System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Model3D' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

please help.
thanks.

Comment: should not you use model3d.Children instead of model3d.Content?

Comment: @SmartMan, do you mean: `(model3d.Content as GeometryModel3D).Material = mat;` instead of internal `foreach` loop?

Comment: @SmartMan, so add if before: `if (model3d.Content != null && model3d.Content is GeometryModel3D) (model3d.Content as GeometryModel3D).Material = mat;`

Comment: @dkozl : Thanks alot. it works. how i can give credit to you?

Comment: @SmartMan, I've added my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelVisual3D.Content` is a single `System.Windows.Media.Media3D` object and that why it's complaining about `foreach` loop. Instead of the inner loop just cast `Content` as `GeometryModel3D` and change its `Material` like below:

```
DiffuseMaterial mat = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));

foreach (ModelVisual3D model3d in previewport.Children)
{
    var geometryModel = model3d.Content as GeometryModel3D;
    if (geometryModel != null) geometryModel.Material = mat;
}
```